# Show that there exist constants $c_0,...c_n$ s.t. the Lagrange polynomial can be rewritten

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

I have to show that there exist constants $c_0,...c_n$ s.t. the polynomial
$$
P(x)=y_0 \frac{(x-x_1)...(x-x_n)}{(x_0-x_1)...(x_0-x_n)} + ... + y_n \frac{(x-x_0)...(x-x_{n-1})}{(x_n-x_0)...(x_n-x_{n-1)}}
$$

can be rewritten as
$P(x)=c_0+c_1(x-x_0)+c_2(x-x_0)(x-x_1)+...+c_n(x-x_{n-1})$

How can I show that such constants exist, and ultimately find them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a change of basis; they are both linearly independent sets of size  $n+1$ In the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$, hence they are both bases. To find them is to find the matrix representation of the change of basis.

Comment: You can get a formula proceeding recursively: $P(x_0)=y_0\implies c_0=y_0;$ $P(x_1)=y_1\implies y_0+c_1(x_1-x_0)=y_1\implies c_1=...$